# How to test empty string and space requests in soap ui?

Tags: rest, soapui, web-api-testing

I want to test following soap ui test scenarios.How to send those requests?I feel both scenarios are works similar in soap ui?

test1 request empty name parameter - name=""

test2 request name parameter as a space - name=" "

Comment: Would you mind showing a screen to understand the context?

Comment: i want to send a empty string and white space to the  Rest web service to check the response. So how to test those two test scenarions usin soapUI ?

Comment: what happened when you tried in the manner that you have mentioned the question?